# python: invalid value encountered in true_divide - but where?

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing

I have a question regarding the following problem:

I want to plot the following easy function:

f(x) = x_1*x_2/(x_1^2+x_2^2)

If x & y are zero you would divide by zero, so I added an exception to prevent this case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def f(x1, x2):
    return np.where(np.logical_and(x1==0,x2==0),
                    0,
                    x1*x2/(x1*x1+x2*x2))

n = 3 
x = y = np.linspace(-5,5,n)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = f(xv,yv)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xv,yv,z)
plt.show()
```

My figure is plot and if I inspect my solution it seems also to be correct. However if I run the code I get a division error:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
```

I tested already the np.where function manually and it returns the x_1=x_2=0 value as true. That seems to work.

Does anybody know where this warning comes from?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Your code works fine for me and plots a graph

Comment: The arguments to `np.where()` are all *evaluated*, so using it like that won't eliminate the error.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser if I understand you correctly 'x1*x2/(x1*x1+x2*x2)' is also evaluated for x1=x2=0. Do you know a better way than np.where() to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been pointed out, you will evaluate every case using `np.where()`. To avoid the error just code it in a lower level such as

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def f(x1, x2):
    shape = np.shape(x1) 
    y = np.zeros(shape)
    for i in range(0,shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,shape[1]):
            if x1[i,j]!=0 and x2[i,j]!=0:
                y[i,j] = x1[i,j]*x2[i,j]/(x1[i,j]*x1[i,j]+x2[i,j]*x2[i,j])
    return y

n = 3 
x = y = np.linspace(-5,5,n)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = f(xv,yv)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xv,yv,z)
plt.show()
```